# Refusing incoming connections to TCP Server

Tags: qt, tcp

In my program I'd like to set the limit of clients for my TCP server.

Currently my code for incoming connections is:

```
void TCPServer::incomingConnection(int handle)
{
    QPointer<TCPClient> client = new TCPClient(this);
    client->SetSocket(handle);

    clients[handle] = client;

    QObject::connect(client, SIGNAL(MessageRecieved(int,QString)), this, SLOT(MessageRecieved(int,QString)));
    QObject::connect(client, SIGNAL(ClientDisconnected(int)), this, SLOT(ClientDisconnected(int)));

    emit ClientConnected(handle);
}
```

Now I'd like to limit the number of clients to for example 100 total active connections.
Do I have to handle it in some special way or just ignore it by using simple `if(clients.count() < 100)` statement?

```
void TCPServer::incomingConnection(int handle)
{
    if(clients.count() < 100)
    {
        QPointer<TCPClient> client = new TCPClient(this);
        client->SetSocket(handle);

        clients[handle] = client;

        QObject::connect(client, SIGNAL(MessageRecieved(int,QString)), this, SLOT(MessageRecieved(int,QString)));
        QObject::connect(client, SIGNAL(ClientDisconnected(int)), this, SLOT(ClientDisconnected(int)));

        emit ClientConnected(handle);
    }
}
```

Is it ok to do it in that way? Do unhandled connections are active (connected to server) but just not listed in my `clients` dictionary?

Comment: The conditional is the way to go. I don't know QT well enough to provide a good code example, but you need to disconnect and close the unused handle since that represents a connected client. If you're not going to service the client, it'd be rude not to close the connection so they can try again later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QTcpServer::setMaxPendingConnections ( int numConnections )`. It sets the maximum number of incoming connections to QTcpServer.

From the Qt documentation :

> **void QTcpServer::setMaxPendingConnections(int numConnections)**
>
> Sets the maximum number of pending accepted connections to numConnections.
>   QTcpServer will accept no more than numConnections incoming
>   connections before nextPendingConnection() is called. By default, the
>   limit is 30 pending connections.
>
> Clients may still able to connect after the server has reached its
>   maximum number of pending connections (i.e., QTcpSocket can still emit
>   the connected() signal). QTcpServer will stop accepting the new
>   connections, but the operating system may still keep them in queue.

So if the number of connections grows past numConnections the server will stop accepting new connections but the OS may queue them.